# Python Comparison of Strings having "ls -l <>" output

Tags: python

I have 2 strings having data:

```
str 1 = '''ls /var/crash
bbb-metro-3542-1559557457.core.gz    cesd-pslm-4456-1559557475.core.gz
bbb-metro-3542-1559557457.txt        cesd-pslm-4456-1559557475.txt
bbb-metro.20190603.102417+0000.3542  cesd-pslm.20190603.095937+0000.3717
cesd-pslm-3717-1559555977.core.gz    cesd-pslm.20190603.102435+0000.4456
cesd-pslm-3717-1559555977.txt        old
bash-4.1#
'''
str2= '''ls /var/crash
bbb-metro-3542-1559557457.core.gz    cesd-pslm-4456-1559557475.core.gz
bbb-metro-3542-1559557457.txt        cesd-pslm-4456-1559557475.txt
bbb-metro.20190603.102417+0000.3542  cesd-pslm.20190603.095937+0000.3717
cesd-pslm-3717-1559555977.core.gz    cesd-pslm.20190603.102435+0000.4456
cesd-pslm-3717-1559555977.txt        old
'''
```

Now i want to compare these 2 strings and print out the difference.

The Str1 and Str2 can change also during the run as there values gets saved from "ls -l" command which is calling during a function call.

How can these 2 strings can be compared ? The difference needs to be saved in another string because i will then pass the same to a function to fetch the value.

I am trying by changing the variable type to list but its not working.

```
   def ls_output(card)
       pxr_crash = self.send_card_cmd(
          card, "ls /var/crash")
      pxr_old = self.send_card_cmd(
          card, "ls /var/crash/old")
      return pxr_crash.resp,pxr_old.resp
```

The return values are str1 and str2 respectively.

```
I am expecting is str1 = '''ls -l /stat
-r--r--r--  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 version
-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 vmallocinfo
'''
and str2 = '''ls -l /stat
-r--r--r--  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 version
-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 vmallocinfo
-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 zone
'''
```

so i should get

```
-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 zone
```

Comment: split strings in list of lines and then every line from `str1` check in list of lines from `str2`

Comment: you can also convert list of lines to `set()` and do `set1 - set2` to get difference

Comment: Are you seriously using `ls` from python?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html

Comment: @cdarke +1, this or the new ``pathlib``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split strings to list of lines and check every line from `str1` in list of lines from `str2`

You can also convert list of lines into `set()` and do `set2 - set1` to get new elements.

```
str1 = '''ls -l /stat
-r--r--r--  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 version
-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 vmallocinfo
'''

str2 = '''ls -l /stat
-r--r--r--  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 version
-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 vmallocinfo
-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 zone
'''

set1 = set(str1.split('\n'))
set2 = set(str2.split('\n'))

print(set2-set1)

# {'-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 zone'}
```

You can also check `set1 - set2` to get elements which were removed.

```
print(set1-set2)

# set()
```

---

`set()` doesn't have to keep order of elements so if you have many differences then they can be in different order every time you run it. You may have to convert back to list and use `sorted()` to get list with the same order every time you run it.

Comment: sorted(list(set2-set1)) gives me                                                                                ['-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     874 Jun  6 10:51 bbb-metro-2588-1559818317.txt\r\r', '-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     874 Jun  6 10:52 bbb-metro-3660-1559818342.txt\r\r', '-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 2086508 Jun  6 10:52 bbb-metro-3660-1559818342.core.gz\r\r', '-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 2097959 Jun  6 10:51 bbb-metro-2588-1559818317.core.gz\r\r', 'drwx------ 2 root root    4096 Jun  6 10:51 bbb-metro.20190606.105157+0000.2588\r\r', 'total 11724\r\r'] i want to get the file names from this list

Comment: you have two options: 1) use `ls` without option `-l` to get only names. Or use only option `-1` (minus one) to get every name is separated row. 2) every row in `sorted(list())` is a string and you can use string functions to cut some part of string. In most lines name starts at 49th char so you can use slicing `[49:]` - ie. `'-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 zone'[49:]`

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the the excellent answers, I chose this as the best because of it's conciseness and use of examples

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = '''ls -l /stat
-r--r--r--  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 version
-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 vmallocinfo
'''


str2 = '''ls -l /stat
-r--r--r--  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 version
-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 vmallocinfo
-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 zone
'''

#list containing all the lines in str1 not present in str2
l1 = [i for i in str1.split('\n') if i not in str2.split('\n')]
#list containing all the lines in str2 not present in str1
l2 = [i for i in str2.split('\n') if i not in str1.split('\n')]

#printing all the diff lines (l1+l2)
for i in l1 + l2:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension like so:

```
def diff(l1, l2):
  return [x for x in l1 if x not in l2] + [x for x in l2 if x not in l1]

diff(str1.splitlines(), str2.splitlines())
```

The result of diff will contain the lines that are only in one of the two strings

Answer (score 0):

I think the `difflib` from stdlib is your friend.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html#module-difflib

Answer (score 0):

Maybe code below can help:

```py
str1 = '''ls -l /stat
-r--r--r--  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 version
-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 vmallocinfo
'''
str2= '''ls -l /stat
-r--r--r--  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 version
-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 vmallocinfo
-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 zone
'''

# convert string to list, spliting by '\n'
str1 = str1.split('\n')
str1 = list(filter(None, str1))
print('---str1---')
print(str1)

str2 = str2.split('\n')
str2 = list(filter(None, str2))

# get the difference
str1sub = [x for x in str1 if x not in str2]
str2sub = [x for x in str2 if x not in str1]

print('\n---result---')
print(str1sub)
print(str2sub)
```

the output is like:

```
---str1---
['ls -l /stat', '-r--r--r--  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 version', '-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 vmallocinfo']

---result---
[]
['-r--------  1 root  root          0 Jun  6 08:56 zone']
```